# Turbo C++-like editor

Tags: c++, ide

do you know if there is some Borland's Turbo C++ clone text-only IDE or something similar for Unix boxes?

I want to have a C++ IDE (editor/compiler/debugger) in text mode available through my console terminal.

Comment: This is such a weird question. Why would anyone be looking for a clone of Borland Turbo C++?

Comment: That would be a step backwards. Use Vim if you're a good soul, or Emacs if you have no mercy for your fingers or other things composed of living cells. Otherwise, use a GUI IDE.

Comment: *::invokes* `M-x target-heretic Amokrane` *::*

Comment: Setedit seems to be more up to date than RHIDE.

Comment: Use GNU `emacs`  and its *compilation-mode*

Answer (score 3):

There is an application very similar, although not a clone, to Borland editors: [FTE](http://fte.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

http://setedit.sourceforge.net/ is like a maintained version of RHIDE. I had to patch a couple of lines to make it build on Ubuntu 12.10 though.

Comment: Hi, what lines did you have to patch ?

Comment: I don't remember, I just compiled it and changed line by line as the errors came. It was pretty simple stuff if I recall correctly. Probably I had to force cast types and stuff.