# GUI debugger for c++ on linux

Tags: c++, linux, user-interface, debugging

I'm looking for a GUI c++ debugger for Linux. Specifically, I need a debugger capable of dereferencing STL and Boost containers.

I have tried DDD and Eclipse/CDT; both of these debuggers have failed to dereference the aforementioned containers. I admit this may be a result of my lack of experience but I have certainly tried. It is my understanding, at the time of this posting, that latest versions of DDD and Eclipse (Helios) have still not resolved the issue.

Any related advice is appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a debug or release build of Boost?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13698794/193892

Answer (score 12):

[Nemiver](http://projects.gnome.org/nemiver/) deserves to be more known IMHO. I find gdb and ddd so horrible (no offence, they are very powerful in their own way), that I gave up on interactive debugging for "printf debugging" whenever I could, for 15 years. Until I found [Nemiver](http://projects.gnome.org/nemiver/).

<sub>Why I gave up on it then?  I switched from DOS and Windows with Turbo C and Borland C++ to Linux. And going to GDB or DDD was like going from a pure delight of stepping through your code, to something you did if you had *no* other choice.
In fact, I have not seen a debugger anywhere as good as the one in Turbo C. You set triggers, you follow structs and linked lists just by clicking through them etc. One of these days I am going to put a youtube clip up to show the kids these days what they are missing out on. Most tools are *way* better nowadays, but not all of them, by far. End of Rant.</sub>

Comment: Ah, that reminds me a lot of emacs' GUD mode.

Comment: Yes, Emacs is an excellent operating system with many good apps for it. :-) @honk

Answer (score 2):

If DDD gives not what you want, hardly you'll find something different, as everybody uses GDB.

Anyway, you may give a try on

- [Kdbg](http://www.kdbg.org/) if you want a standalone debugger.
- [Kdevelop](http://www.kdevelop.org/) if you want a full IDE.

Kdevelop 4.2 (beta) has some nice features. Hope you have luck.

You may also want to read what others have said:

- [9 of the Best Free Linux Debuggers](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20090624155431809/Debuggers.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use GDB to dereference STL containers with [this in your `.gdbinit`](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/src/dbinit_stl_views-1.03.txt). Choose a graphical front-end to GDB such as DDD or Eclipse, and you should be all set!

Comment: Or just learn how to drive GDB. It's far more powerful than any GUI front-end will expose to you.

Answer (score 1):

DDD is just a GUI frontend to GDB, and Eclipse probably is too (not sure), you need to use GDB macros to pretty-print STL containers, here is some info about it:

http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport

Answer (score 0):

Intel makes excellent C++ debugger and it is free for educational and Non-profit development.
Google - intel compiler non-profit

Answer (score 0):

You also can take a look on Zero Bugs debugger [here](http://www.zerobugs.org/) or [here](http://zerobugs.codeplex.com/)

Comment: That link is dead, Jim. I googled and changed the link, but org address is not perhaps exactly _dead_, but it's not in good shape, that site. Dead links on it.

Answer (score 0):

I would seriously look at the Eclipse and its CDK support, it is quite impressive and can be used on more than just Linux..

- http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/
- http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php

Answer (score 0):

You might consider TotalView, but it's not free.

Answer (score -4):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820390/what-c-ides-on-linux-have-intellisense-in-par-with-or-better-than-visual-st/3820890#3820890) answer applies to C++ debugging in Linux. Lack of good *visual* debugging tools is one of many reasons C++ is extremely unpopular on Linux.

Comment: C++ is extremely popular on all the Linux development I know of.  GDB is a very solid and usable debugger.

Comment: A GUI debugger does not mean a good debugger. For example, the scripting language in GDB makes it far more useful than the default Visual Studio debugger.

Comment: @David: You just don't know how to use it.

Comment: @wallyk: GDB is very solid, but C++ is pretty darn hard to debug without a visual debugger. I use it regularly with C however.

Comment: GDB is terrible to those who can't read the manuals :-)